# libtiff for C using Snow Leopard. Storage size of TIFF isn't know

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, libtiff

I have just built and installed tiff-4.0.0beta6 on my Mac computer running Snow Leopard. I followed the tutorial at http://www.kyngchaos.com/macosx/build/libtiff. The install went fine but there are issues with the TIFF data type.

For exmaple, when I compile the following simple code:

```
#include "tiffio.h"

main()
{
    TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen("foo.tif", "r");
    TIFFClose(tif);
}
```

I get the error message:

```
hlrg-labs-imac:metrics Ben$ gcc main.c
Undefined symbols:
  "_TIFFOpen", referenced from:
      _main in cciewEwr.o
  "_TIFFClose", referenced from:
      _main in cciewEwr.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I compile the code:

```
#include "tiffio.h"

main()
{
    TIFF tif;
}
```

I get the compilation error:

```
hlrg-labs-imac:metrics Ben$ gcc main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:5: error: storage size of ‘tif’ isn’t known
```

Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you compile you need to include the -ltiff switch. For example:

```
gcc main.c -ltiff -o main
```

Also, in your second example it should be

```
main(){ TIFF* tif; }
```